# Using LSM tree like LevelDB as a storage Engine for RDBMS

Tags: rdbms, leveldb, opentsdb, rocksdb, lsm-tree

LSM Tree has been found successful use in many no-sql engines, its data are sorted by keys not like hashing tables thus enabling many potential use beyond a kv store. For example, a time series database (TSDB) may be a good fit using level db as its engine. How about traditional RDBMS and many table systems? Is LSM-tree like data engines are a good fit as well?

Answer (score 1):

It might be. If you're going to design indexes in a way to exploit strengths of leveldb (namely fast sequential reading) then it might work well.

In fact I have build small relational database on top of leveldb ([linqdb](https://github.com/ren85/linqdb)) where index is just sorted values of column stored as key-values. My findings are that querying such structure isn't as fast as sqlite's indexed columns (about 40% slower) but writing outperforms by a big margin.

Of course there are many factors in query speed, LSM is just an underlying data structure which best shines at writing.

Additional info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leveldb/G76tjwYoJgs)

Comment: In fact, we are trying to build a table system, but read or batch write may be the typical use case. Currently we are using a in memory hash index, but that doesn't support range query and sorted query. I am looking at LSM because it doesn't cost that much of memory and its keys are stored ordered.

Comment: @bugs king The LSM is best fit for disk (large chunks of data written as in merge sort), so not sure if its the best thing for in memory index

Comment: I found there is actually a lsm-tree based mysql in development which is called myrocks, but there are too limited resource about their performance and insight of latency.

Comment: comparing read performance with sqlite over a small database is not fair.  sqlite is always faster over small datasets.

Comment: @amirouche I've compared on ~20GB set which isn't exactly small. But the result probably is due to many factors (LSM vs B-tree being one of them)